# Swap environment domain list is empty

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I've followed these steps to try and blue/green my application: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.CNAMESwap.html

Having created a new environment and deployed my app there, I now want to swap the CNAME from the old environment to the new one.

However, the instructions say... "On the environment overview page, choose Actions, and then choose Swap environment URLs" ... but there is no 'Swap environment URLs' options, only a 'Swap environment domain'. If I choose that, there are no options in the list of environments to swap with.

I don't know if the instructions are out of date or if my setup is different?

I've also tried changing the domain record in Route 53 to point at the new environment instead, but that gives me an HTTPS issue.[image]